# Speed up a query with constant list values

Tags: mysql, performance, explain

Is there a way to speed this thing up?

```
SELECT LOWER(nameid), COUNT(nameid) AS cant
FROM infos AS i
WHERE i.value > 0 
AND i.oid IN ($1) 
AND i.nameid IN ($2)
GROUP BY nameid
```

$1
Is a  long list of comma separated IDs like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,etc.

$2
Is a list of comma separated strings like "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", etc.

```
CREATE TABLE `infos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `oid ` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nameid` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value ` mediumint(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CHECKSUM=1;
```

I tried something like this, but the results are not the same:

```
SELECT merkmalid, i.wert FROM infos AS i
WHERE i.oid IN     
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
       SELECT ($1)         
    ) AS sub
    WHERE i.nameid IN ($2)
)
```

Comment: Would creating tables, temporary or otherwise, to contain these lists of strings and IDs be a possibility?  Or, are these lists being generated, e.g. by some app code?

Comment: Is there a reason to use `MyISAM` driver instead of `INNODB`?

Comment: Yeah, these lists are generated by an app and i have to use them in the query.

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu not really. i switched a few to INNOBD and the speed increases quite good. Whats going on?

Comment: Try create index on columns nameid, oid and value.

Comment: @roy if i add an index like that the query actually gets slower

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `IN ( 1,2,3 )` and `IN ( "1,2,3" )`.  You probably want the former.  I can't tell what the first `SELECT` gives you.  Please provide the `SELECT` *after* interpolation.

The subquery can give you only the latter.

I recommend `INDEX(nameid, oid, value)` as the most likely to help.  Once you have that index, you may need InnoDB to make full use of it.